# break one line into multiple lines but repeating the names using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, unix

I have an input file (fixed width format) text file like this:

```
id1|col2|col3|...|timestamp1,timestamp2,timestamp3,timestamp4,timestamp5  
id2|col2|col3|...|timestamp1,timestamp2  
id3|col2|col3|...|timestamp1  
...
```

IDs have different numbers of timestamps. The desired output should be structured as: each id should have one timestamp, 2nd timestamp should be on a different line with the same ids in front.

```
id1|col2|col3|...|timestamp1  
id1|col2|col3|...|timestamp2  
id1|col2|col3|...|timestamp3  
id1|col2|col3|...|timestamp4    
id1|col2|col3|...|timestamp5    
id2|col2|col3|...|timestamp1  
id2|col2|col3|...|timestamp2  
id3|col2|col3|...|timestamp1
```

I have tried to read it in sql, but it is kind of tedious. I am looking to see if there is an answer in Python or unix. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Before asking people to write code for you, please show us what you have tried before posting the question. Asking a question like this without any code looks like a homework and that is not what stackoverflow is for.

Comment: I am not familiar with Unix or Python. I tried to use sql's substring function. But I was not able to get the desired output.

Comment: I googled for some code like this, but it need to be modified as my file is different:    
for line in open("h2.txt"):  
    line=line.strip().split(",")  
    for item in line[1:]:  
        if "," in item:              item=item.split(",")
        else:
            item=item.split()
        for i in item:
            print "%s|%s" %(line[0],i)

Comment: @Dvorog's first sentence is correct and should be heeded. Second sentence is incorrect and should be ignored. Source: SO Help *describes how* to ask for homework help: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @AdamSmith maybe I should rephrase my second sentence. What I was trying to say is that asking a question without showing any effort to solve it by yourself is not what you should do on stackoverflow. When I see a question like that it looks to me like the user didn't even research the problem and expects that posting it here will magically solve everything (I am not talking about the current question, I am talking in general).

Comment: @Dvorog Noted and agreed. I think the SO "homework" debate is distraction when all questions should be held to the same standards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use split('|') to cut your line using `|`delimiter, and then split(',') to cut the final field into a list of timestamps

```
with open('/path/to/file', 'r') as f:  
    for line in f:
        fields = line.split('|')
        timestamps = fields[-1].split(',')
        for timestamp in timestamps:
            print('|'.join(fields[:-1]+[timestamp]))
```

Comment: Thank you Gelineau. This worked:    with open('h6.txt', 'r') as f:  
    for line in f:
        line=line.strip()
        fields = line.split('|')
        timestamps = fields[-1].split(',')
        for timestamp in timestamps:
            print('|'.join(fields[:-1]+[timestamp]))